# Admob wide_skyscraper AdSize supported?

Tags: android, admob, ads

Is the AdSize wide_skyscraper supported since it will show ads when requested, however the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize.html#WIDE_SKYSCRAPER) says its not supported. Does anyone know if works if I implement this in a app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's deprecated according to GADAdSize.h in the iOS library, at the bottom it says:

```
#pragma mark Deprecated Macros

#define GAD_SIZE_320x50 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner)
#define GAD_SIZE_320x100 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeLargeBanner)
#define GAD_SIZE_300x250 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle)
#define GAD_SIZE_468x60 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeFullBanner)
#define GAD_SIZE_728x90 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeLeaderboard)
#define GAD_SIZE_120x600 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSkyscraper)
```